# Insert in column names with blank space in sqlite3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to fill a sqlite3 database with Python3 with data stored in a dict. The problem in my code seems to be in this snippet.

```
matchlist=['id','handicap','goal line','corner line']
heads='"'+'","'.join([a for a in list(match.keys()) if a in matchlist])+'"'
llaves=':'+',:'.join([a for a in list(match.keys()) if a in matchlist])

cur.execute('''INSERT or IGNORE INTO preodds ({}) VALUES ({});'''.format(heads,llaves),
            match)
```

This gives me an operational error next to line.

Apparently, when you try to insert in columns which name has blank spaces youneed to"escape" them. To do so, I modified as well my llaves string, doing the following:

```
llaves='":'+'",":'.join([a for a in list(match.keys()) if a in matchlist])+'"'
```

Doing so fix my issue, but instead of filling the table with the value provided my the dict, it is filled with the literal value in llaves string.

Why is this? and more importantly, if i have a table with columns with blank spaces, how do you fill rows using dict data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code is likely producing this

```
INSERT or IGNORE INTO preodds ("id","handicap","goal line","corner line")
 VALUES (:id,:handicap,:goal line,:corner line)
```

Notice the spaces in the parameters names... the names starting with colon (`:`).  That's the problem.

Your attempted solution is just submitting string literals as values, so that is exactly what is inserted.

```
INSERT or IGNORE INTO preodds ("id","handicap","goal line","corner line")
 VALUES (":id",":handicap",":goal line",":corner line")
```

Quotes can be used to delimit object names, but **in other contexts quotes are interpreted as literal string value delimiters**.  Precise rules for determining how it interprets quoted values are found [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).

As far as I can tell, parameters cannot be escaped and so cannot contain spaces or other special characters, at least nothing that is documented.  See [sqlite docs](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html).

If you are going to build the parameter list dynamically, you should strip out all spaces from the parameter names.  Or alternatively, you could just use unnamed parameters using the `?` character.  Either way the parameters are assigned values in the order they appear, so there would be no difference.

Something like:

```
INSERT or IGNORE INTO preodds ("id","handicap","goal line","corner line")
 VALUES (:id,:handicap,:goalline,:cornerline)
```

or

```
INSERT or IGNORE INTO preodds ("id","handicap","goal line","corner line")
 VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: You could try one other alternative for the parameters.  Put the quotes AFTER the colon.  If this works then great, but even if it doesn't work, the general principle is that you should never put quotes around an operator (or other special characters), since quotes encapsulate, group, and change the meaning of special characters.  In other words, try this instead:  `':"'+'",:"'.join([a for a in list(match.keys()) if a in matchlist])+'"'`.  This will produce `:"goal line"` which is much more likely to work as intended.

Comment: I tried your latter approach, but didn't work out. So in the end, I underscored all names with a blank space and that solved the issue.